# Thinking about the visa expiration vs end of period of stay terminology question

Tags: discussion

This is a meta question just to hold our opinions and polling and working out for [my main site question on this topic](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/53080/what-is-a-clear-way-to-express-the-end-of-a-period-of-time-im-allowed-to-stay-i).

The main site should only have factual answers but, perhaps due to how I first worded the question, it seemed to be asking for opinions and polling.

So if we have to nut it out let's do that here. Once we know the facts we can post a factual answer to the question on the main site.

1. A factual answer might be which terms each country uses, might uncover some industry term, etc.
2. Or a factual answer might be "there's no standard clear way".

But until we're sure that the situation is 1. or 2. we should use this question to think about it.

Comment: I think it's a wonderful question, but then I applaud any movement towards becoming precise with our terminology.  Using the correct terms is something that gives distinction to the site.

Comment: @GayotFow Are we developing our own terminology, then? We have already seen that each country expresses these concepts differently, as should be expected given that every country's immigration rules are different.

Comment: I think knowing and understanding the limitations of the terminology is part and parcel of "using the correct terms". There could well be some cases when developing some terminology of our own might make sense and/or be useful too though.